# bash scripting, invoke function as a conditional test

Tags: bash, scripting

Can someone please tell me why line 7 (if statement) generates an error:

```
test.sh: line 7: [: command_exists: unary operator expected
```

thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

command_exists () {
  command -v "$1" &> /dev/null ;
}

if [ ! command_exists ruby ]; then  # test.sh: line 7: [: command_exists: unary operator expected
  echo 'found ruby'
else
  echo 'ruby not found'
fi
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
if ! command_exists ruby; then
```

In Bash, `if` executes a command and acts on its return value. `[` happens to be a command.